# Comparing user input to String Array list

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

So i've been trying to do this for a couple of days, been searchin' and trying different stuff, but none of them seem to work for me. I wan't to compare user input to the String ArrayList and see if it has that value. I do this to prevent users to send in whatever text they want, only what is in the String ArrayList. Here's the simplified code:

`

```
        private ArrayList<String> searchNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        EditText nameCaptureNo;
        EditText nameCaptureUz;
        Button send;
        TextView tvTi;



        public void sendTestMsg() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


             for (int i = 0; i < searchNames.size(); i++) {
                 if            (searchNames.get(i).toString().toUpperCase()
                                      .contains(nameCaptureNo
                         .getText().toString().toUpperCase()) && 
                                  searchNames.get(i).toString().toUpperCase()
                                      .contains(nameCaptureUz
                         .getText().toString().toUpperCase()) ) {

            send.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   //here goes code wich sends info
        }else{
                     send.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                         //warning                   
                             tvTi.setText("Izvēlies pilsētu no saraksta!");
                     tvTi.setTextColor(Color.RED);

                     continue;
                 }
                 break;
             }
```

`

This is as far as I've gotten. This code seems to be sending the info, but the textview still changes to warning.
Can you help? Many thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code working as below

You don't need to change to upper case. use equalsIgnoreCase as below,

```
public boolean checkString(String value)
{
boolean found = false;

for(String searchcontent:searchNames)
{
if((searchcontent).equalsIgnoreCase(value))
{
                found = true;
                break;
            }

        }


        return found;
}
```

[image]

Complete code as below,

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.userinput;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


      private ArrayList<String> searchNames = new ArrayList<String>();
      EditText nameCaptureNo;
      EditText nameCaptureUz;
      Button send;
      TextView tvTi;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        nameCaptureNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameCaptureNo);
        nameCaptureUz = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameCaptureUz);




        nameCaptureNo.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Text Modified "+ nameCaptureNo.getText().toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

                Log.d("MainActivity", "Text Modified "+ nameCaptureNo.getText().toString());
                if(checkString(nameCaptureNo.getText().toString()))
                {
                    send.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else
                {
                    send.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    //warning                   
                    tvTi.setText("Izvēlies pilsētu no saraksta!");
                    tvTi.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Log.d("MainActivity", "Text Modified "+ nameCaptureNo.getText().toString());

            }

        });

        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);

        //Set the send button invisible 
        send.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        tvTi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTi);


        searchNames.add("Test1");
        searchNames.add("Test2");
        searchNames.add("Test3");
        searchNames.add("Test4");
        searchNames.add("Test5");
        searchNames.add("Test6");
    }

    public boolean checkString(String value)
    {
        boolean found = false;

        for(String searchcontent:searchNames)
        {
            if((searchcontent).equalsIgnoreCase(value))
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }

        }


        return found;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvTi"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="nameCaptureNo"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="nameCaptureUz"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nameCaptureUz"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nameCaptureNo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nameCaptureUz"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Send" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nameCaptureNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">UserInput</string>
    <string name="hello_world">TextView tvTi</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: This is perfect! Works like a charm! BIG thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

use `.equals` to compare,so change

```
if(searchNames.get(i).toString().toUpperCase()
                                          .contains(nameCaptureNo
                             .getText().toString().toUpperCase()) ) {
```

to

```
 if(searchNames.get(i).toString().toUpperCase()
                                      .equals(nameCaptureNo
                         .getText().toString().toUpperCase()) ) {
```

Or directly use `.contains` as

And no need to loop searchNames,so use below code for `.contains`,Therefore change

```
   for (int i = 0; i < searchNames.size(); i++) {
                 if            (searchNames.get(i).toString().toUpperCase()
                                      .contains(nameCaptureNo
                         .getText().toString().toUpperCase()) ) {

            send.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   //here goes code wich sends info
        }else{
                     send.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                         //warning                   
                             tvTi.setText("Izvēlies pilsētu no saraksta!");
                     tvTi.setTextColor(Color.RED);

                     continue;
                 }
                 break;
             }
```

to

```
if(searchNames.contains(nameCaptureNo.getText().toString().toUpperCase()){
  send.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else{
  send.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   //warning                   
    tvTi.setText("Izvēlies pilsētu no saraksta!");
   tvTi.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Note: save `searchNames` values in `uppercase`.

Comment: Hey! Many thanks. I had tried this but before it didn't worked, but I finally found where I have my mistake. It is not because of IF statement. I had put two comparisons in one for loop, because I need to compare both EditTexts and that's my mistake. It works only when both of ET's are equal and that also I want to prevent.

Comment: @user3783123 ok,bro,if this answer helped you,then please accept it,so  it may help others also having similar issue.

Comment: @user3783123 and you can directly use contains instead of loop.

Answer (score 0):

You do all the changes form the loop. However there needs to be only one element, that makes your if condition `true` for the string to be valid/sended. If in some previous loop iteration the else block gets executed, it shouldn't trigger the warning. Change your for loop to something like this:

```
boolean found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < searchNames.size(); i++) {
    if (searchNames.get(i).toString().toUpperCase()
           .contains(nameCaptureNo
                       .getText().toString().toUpperCase())) {
        found = true;
        // save additional info you need to call send to variables here
        break;
    }
}
if (found) {
    send.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //here goes code wich sends info
} else {
    send.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    //warning                   
    tvTi.setText("Izvēlies pilsētu no saraksta!");
    tvTi.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Also `s1.contains(s2)` checks, if `s2` is a substring of `s1`, i.e. `s1="Hello World!"` and `s2="World"` would yield true. you may want to use `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          boolean isContain = false;
          for (int i = 0; i < searchNames.size(); i++) {
                if (searchNames.get(i).toString().toUpperCase().contains(nameCaptureNo.getText().toString().toUpperCase())) {
                     isContain = true;
                     break;
                 }
          }
          if(isContain){
              send.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              tvTi.setText("");
              //here goes code wich sends info
          }else{
              send.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              tvTi.setText("Izvēlies pilsētu no saraksta!");
              tvTi.setTextColor(Color.RED);
          }
     }
});
```